# Most common page replacement algorithm used in CPUs

Tags: memory, memory-management, cpu, paging, cpu-architecture

What is the most common [page replacement algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm) used in CPUs today? Is there a de facto algorithm that major CPU designers like Intel and ARM use? A lot of the text I'm finding describes the various algorithms but not how popular they are.

Comment: Page replacement algorithms are implemented in the OS, not the CPU. There is no one particularly "popular" algorithm. Different OSs use different techniques and different versions and flavors of the same OS use different techniques.

Comment: I suggest removing the `memory` and `cpu-architecture` tags and adding the `operating-system` tag.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought the MMU handled page replacement (and by extension the CPU). Do you know what Linux and Windows use?

Comment: The MMU on x86 gives the OS the info it needs, by updating Accessed and Dirty bits in the page-table entry, if they were cleared before an access.  I assume other ISAs are similar.  But the MMU hardware doesn't know which pages are copy-on-write mapped from which, or how to load a page from disk, so the OS has to be involved; might as well have it implement the code that decides which page to evict, too.